# Ubuntu : Execution was not ending properly before test completion

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Ubuntu: Execution was not ending properly before test completion

I have two questions 
1) I am running 4500 users test from two machines (2250+2250). Duration of the test is 1 hr 30 min.

At the end test was not closing and it's not giving a consolidated summary in the console.

[image]

2) after closing the test by keys(ctrl +C). If I open the jtl report from the master system its showing 2250 users in the (Active threads over time) Lisner.

Answer (score 0):

Using ctrl+c is not enough for terminating the running process.

End your test by executing the shutdown.sh (or bat depending on your environment) to signal the running process to properly and gracefully end its execution. See here: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html

Edit: you can use the stoptest.cmd|sh for forcing a stop.

Comment: Yes, But I have waited for a long time complete the test so I used ctrl+c, I will look into the shared link.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your execution log file my expectation is that your are kicking off 9000 threads. When it comes to [remote testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) JMeter Remote Engines are **absolutely independent** so each engine is executing the [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) it receives from the master.

If you define 4500 threads in the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)(s) it means that **every** JMeter slave will kick off 4500 virtual users.

The fact that JMeter doesn't respond to `Shutdown` event indicates the fact that JMeter engines are overloaded so they even cannot gracefully shutdown in a reasonable time. Make sure you have monitoring of at least baseline CPU and Memory stats of JMeter load generators to ensure that they have enough headroom to operate as if they will be lacking resources it will result in the increased response time (and impossibility to shut the test down as well).
So my recommendations are:

1. Make sure the load you deliver matches your expectations as I am under the impression you are delivering twice as many users

   [image: JMeter 4500 users started]
2. Make sure you have monitoring of CPU, RAM, Network and Disk capacity on JMeter load generators, you can use i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this.
3. Make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Comment: Hi Dimitri, In each machine, I am running a test with 2250 users. So in the two slave machines, it will become 4500 users.  But I am checking in the consolidated report(.jtl) which is generated on the master machine. The active threads count it is showing 2250 users only.